# How to give Tag based access to IAM user group in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

This question is for AWS and I am looking for a cutom policy to be created.
I have a group called IOT-grp and there are few instances, which are tagged as IOT (Key is Environment and Value is IOT). I am looking to fulfill two requirements.

1- I want to have policy created, which can allow any user, who is part of IOT group, should be able to start/stop/reboot only instances, which are marked as IOT.

2- Along with that, any user in IOT group should be able to terminate (only IOT instances) and create new instances (for IOT only). There are different security groups for IOT, Prod and QA instances.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Start by reading about **Restricting users to tagged instances** on [Demystifying EC2 Resource-Level Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/demystifying-ec2-resource-level-permissions/). It gives the example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "TheseActionsSupportResourceLevelPermissionsWithInstancesAndTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:StartInstances"],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/Environment": "Prod"}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am able to test that prod user can stop/start instances. But, is there any way, I can give access to prod user, to create instances and select Security Groups intended for prod instances ? Out security groups are names as "oraws-prod-dmz01" or oraws-qa-db02". We want respective teams to have access to terminate and create their own instances. If we open them to create any instance, qa users will create instance and associate prod security group to their instance and will gain access to production network, which is not secure. Any alternate or better way ?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to force usage of a particular Security Group. If you need to enforce this, then you should have users request their instance via an intermediary app (that you write), which will launch the instances for them but will enforce your standards. You then remove permissions for the users to launch instances themselves.